# I can authenticate to github with my local ssh key but still get annoying github popup to request login user, pass

Tags: git, github

I can authenticate by following this example:
https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/testing-your-ssh-connection

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

> Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
> provide shell access.

Yet when I do anything like push to my repo or pull a submodule i get annoying github login dialogue, which even on entering username/pass still doesn't work and asks me to enter username/pass into cmd.

After removing - credential-manager

```
git credential-manager remove -force
```

It removes annoying popup but still requests me to enter both the username, password via command line, despite having ssh key.

Comment: Are you actually using ssh? It sounds to me like you might be using https instead? Try double checking the remote to make sure it isn't a https URL

Comment: @thsutton - ah, that could be it. Thankyou