# GitHub credential prompt issue. GitHub login screen pops up everytime I push

Tags: git, github, push, credentials, pull

I am using PyCharm IDE and have linked Git bash to the terminal within the IDE. Every time I push, there is a screen which pops up:
[Github Login Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5rTI.png)

This occurs both using the IDE and using git bash directly. If I cancel the screen, the push is completed without actually asking for credentials. The issue seems to just be with this prompt popping up.
I have also run the credential helper which got rid of the issue of entering my credentials within the terminal.

Just need to know how I could eliminate this prompt pop up??

Comment: did you clone/add remote with ```https``` or ```ssh```? try usjng ```ssh``` with ssh keys

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66332299/i-can-authenticate-to-github-with-my-local-ssh-key-but-still-get-annoying-github